# Should I use an application server?

Tags: java, glassfish

I'm developing a Java application which will act as a server for an information retrieval application. In the past, I've run the Java application in a screen with the command `java -jar MyApp.jar`.

Recently, I've been using Glassfish for hosting a web app, and I like the way it handles applications and deals with deploying, starting, etc.

What benefits are there to using Glassfish or another application server for containing my application? Are there any potential problems with it? Would it be better to just go with the screen method?

Thanks.

Comment: If you like it, stick with it. Not sure you need any other reason to use it. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you build the app to run on an application server, you can expose your data using standard mechanisms such as REST or SOAP services.  You won't have to deal with lower level TCP or Java RMI to communicate, it takes care of that for you.  Basically, you get a ton of functions for "free" by deploying your app to an application server.

The only con I can think of is that there is some overhead.  Just firing up Glassfish, with nothing running on it, is certainly going to consume a substantial chunk of memory.  Your application just adds more overhead on top of that.

Answer (score 0):

Many application servers e.g. GlassFish, JBoss, WebSphere Application Server, etc. are designed to conform to the [Java EE Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=316). So you don't have to worry about managing your Java EE application. If your webapp is compiled successfully, according to the Java EE Specification, your application server can run it.